# Copying filesystem metadata (modifyDate etc) from one file to another

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, metadata

I´m reconverting my old files, and using the following code to copy metadata from the old file to the new one:

```
for %%f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -i "%%~nf_1.mp4" -map 1 -c copy -map_metadata 0 -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a "%%~nf_.mp4"
```

However, this doesn´t copy file system metadata such as modified date.
Is there any way to copy that metadata? Any suggestion?

Thanks.

PS I´m on Windows 10

Comment: Why are you re-encoding the file? Of course it will have the date-time of now. Why not use the Copy command?

Comment: I'm reencoding my old videos to HEVC to free some space, as my library is getting bigger and it doesn´t make sense.
These are from my old Xiaomi Yi camera, whose videos are extremely heavy (and quality not that good). Converting them to HEVC I could reduce size to a third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meta-data that copies ffmpeg is the data associated with the video.
The modified-date is an attribute of the file, managed by Windows but not by ffmpeg.

If you have converted the files from the folder `C:\dirsource` to folder `D:\dirtarget`,
then the following PowerShell script will copy the modified date from source
to target:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\dirtarget\" *.mp4 | ForEach-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime = (Get-Item ("C:\dirsource\"+$_.Name)).LastWriteTime
}
```

You may also do the same with the attributes `CreationTime` and `LastAccessTime`.

Create a file named `myname.ps1` and copy inside the above text.
Start a PowerShell session, use `cd` to position to the folder containing
the script, then run the command `.\myname.ps1`.

If you receive an error message saying
"Cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system",
run the following command in the PowerShell window and then repeat the above:

```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks a lot for your explanation!!